# Python File Handling and Counting Duplicates One Time

Tags: python-3.x

I'm looking to handle a case where I need to read from the file, count the number of people (duplicates) only once, and then write the output in a separate file. I'm confused as to which data structure to use for counting people only once for a single class that they are in. The input and output is mentioned below:

Input:

10  
4  
A-Class Midoriya  
B-Class Monoma  
A-Class Todoroki  
A-Class Midoriya

11  
2  
A-Class Aizawa  
B-Class All Might

Output 
Case: 10  
A-Class 2  
B-Class 1

Case: 11  
A-Class 1  
B-Class 1

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a set, possibly a dict of sets: a set keeps a single occurrence of duplicate inputs and so is a good way to treat items as unique, a dict is useful if you need multiple "categories" each with their own unique list. Although you could alternatively use a set of (category, item) tuples.

Your input and output make no sense though, case 10 has 2 unique Class A individuals and 1 unique Class B, not 3 and 2.

Comment: How would I go about counting them ? And how to make a dict of sets? Thanks for your help.